# Laravel - How to use Auth user inside the global scope

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, global-scope, laravel-models

I want to use Auth user in the global scope

**User.php**

```
 public function scopeActive($query)
 {
      return $query->where('accessed_id', auth()->user()->accessed_id);
 }

 protected static function boot()
 {
        parent::boot();    
        static::addGlobalScope('customer_user', function (Builder $builder) {
            if(auth()->check()){  // check user is auth or not
                 $builder->active();
            }  
        });
 }
```

I am unable to get auth user in scope because the scope was early called then after authentication, It's possible to get auth user in the global scope?

Comment: Seems like the logic here is flawed. Since a global scope is applied to every query, you're creating an infinite loop by querying within the scope definition.

Comment: @MrEduar Yes but I want to put default where in each user condition for every query

Comment: Maybe you need a policy, check the Authorization docs